# What are the connections between Okorafor's works?

Tags: nnedi-okorafor

Some of Nnedi Okorafor's books are set in the same continuity. But I am not sure which ones are, or if they all are.

- *The Book of Phoenix* is clearly a prequel to *Who Fears Death*.
- *Zahrah the Windseeker* is set in Ginen, which also plays a role in *The Shadow Speaker*, and is of course the setting of "The Lost Diary of Treefrog7." It seems like *Akata Witch* might be connected here, too?

But it seems difficult to reconcile the ending of *Lagoon* with *The Shadow Speaker*, let alone the latter with *The Book of Phoenix*. And it's not clear where the *Binti* series fits, if at all.

**Are her books all in the same universe? Or, if not, which ones are?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nnedi Okorafor has two universes that get shared between her original novels, plus some work within the Marvel universes. [Okorafor recently posted to Twitter](https://twitter.com/nnedi/status/1016813466261295106):

> Lagoon, LaGuardia (my forthcoming comic series/graphic novel) and Binti trilogy are all in the same universe.
>
> The Akata books, Remote Control (forthcoming novel), The Book of Phoenix, and Who Fears Death are all in the same universe (& connected to Zahrah the Windseeker)

So this means for one universe there are the following books:

- [Lagoon](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18753656-lagoon)
- [Binti](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25667918-binti)
- [Binti: Home](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30038654-home)
- [Binti: The Night Masquerade](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34386617-the-night-masquerade)
- The comic series [LaGuardia](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/42762071-laguardia5)

For the other universe, which you and other fans know as the Ginen universe:

- [Akata Witch](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7507944-akata-witch)
- [Akata Warrior](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18746776-akata-warrior)
- [Who Fears Death](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7767021-who-fears-death)
- [The Book of Phoenix](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23281789-the-book-of-phoenix) (a prequel to Who Fears Death)
- [Remote Control](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34215764-remote-control) (a prequel to Phoenix, see discussion [here](https://www.tor.com/2021/07/27/exploring-nnedi-okorafors-africanfuturist-universe/))

[Zahrah the Windseeker](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Zahrah-Windseeker-Nnedi-Okorafor-Mbachu/dp/0547020287) is “connected” to this universe but not “in” it, so I'm not sure what that means for its canonical placement. Okorafor explains [at the beginning of this youtube interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqYtmKtdLYo) that the Ginen universe's name has a particular meaning, so it may be that Zahrah was borne out of the same themes but doesn't exist chronologically and physically in the same realm as these stories:

> **Okorafor:** The word “ginen” is [an idea that] enslaved Africans used to refer to the Africa that they couldn't remember. So I always remember that phrase ginen, ginen, ginen, that word ginen, and when I created this world that was what I wanted to name it. I guess really it's the mythical Africa. It's what is remembered in the mind and in the soul, in the body, in the spirit. It's the Africa that exists but doesn't exist. So that's where that came from, and then it just sort of took on its own shape after I started writing about it.

[Nnedi Okorafor has also been writing for Marvel Comics recently](https://www.marvel.com/comics/creators/13208/nnedi_okorafor) which is technically a whole new universe added to her works (or more than one, given Marvel's various timelines). These currently include the following series:

- [Black Panther: Long Live the King](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/65319/black_panther_-_long_live_the_king_2017_1)
- [Amazing Spider-Man: Wakanda Forever](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/67307/amazing_spider-man_wakanda_forever_2018_1)
- [X-Men: Wakanda Forever](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/67593/x-men_wakanda_forever_2018_1)
- [Shuri](https://www.tor.com/2018/07/18/nnedi-okorafor-is-penning-a-comic-about-black-panthers-sister-shuri/), a comic series about the sister of T'Challa, the Black Panther.

Comment: Note that in *Akata Woman*, the connection between Ginen and Sunny's Earth is clarified: they are separate worlds that can be accessed by traveling through the wilderness.

Comment: I'll leave it to you (or someone else) to edit it in, but _LaGuardia_ has been out for some time now, as are _Remote Control_ and _Noor_,

Answer (score -3):

They are all a part of the Ginen Universe Nnedi Okorafor talks about it in a youtube video

Comment: **Which** youtube video?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqYtmKtdLYo here it is

Comment: Great, now add that to your answer (along with a quick transcript of the relevant bit) using the [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/186531/edit) button.