# How is Remote Control connected to Ginen?

Tags: nnedi-okorafor, remote-control

According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192132/51379) to a previous  question, the novella *Remote Control* is connected to *Zarah the Windseeker* and other books by Nnedi Okorafor that touch on the world of Ginen.

However, having read it, it seems to take place entirely in a near-future version of Earth, and the protagonist never travels to Ginen, nor does she seem to meet anyone from that world. As such, what is the connection between *Remote Control* and the other Ginen works?