# How is Noor connected to other books by Nnedi Okorafor?

Tags: nnedi-okorafor, noor

[This excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/192132/158854) describes the connections between many of Nnedi Okorafor, but doesn't include *Noor*, which was published more recently.

Okorafor [commented](https://twitter.com/Nnedi/status/1396483204853338116?s=20&t=GGDMSx7Ya43Tebg1GsgaWQ) on a Twitter post containing a connection diagram between her books, clarifying:

> My forthcoming novel NOOR is in the same world as my short story "Mother of Invention".

This story was [published in Slate in 2018](https://slate.com/technology/2018/02/mother-of-invention-a-new-short-story-by-nnedi-okorafor.html).

Is there a connection between this world and the others?